# Instant messaging system

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm now developing an instant messaging system but I'm a little confused: I can't decide which approach I have to choose!

I want you to tell me what is good/bad with this programming approach.  One friend of mine said it's difficult to read, but it works.

```
/*! | (c) 2012, 2013 by Bellashh*/
 /// <reference path="jquery-2.0.0-vsdoc.js" />
$(document).ready(function () {
  var ChatProvider = {
    "Friends": [],
    "People": [],
    "Conferences": [],
    "UI": {},
    "Utils": {
      "functions": {
        "alert": function (str) {
          alert(str);
        } /*ChatProvider.Utils.functions.alert*/ ,

        "addFriend": function (friend) {
          ChatProvider.Friends.push(friend);
          alert(ChatProvider.Friends.pop().Names);
        } /*ChatProvider.Utils.functions.addFriend*/ ,

      } /*ChatProvider.Utils.functions*/ ,

      "events": {} /*ChatProvider.Utils.events*/ ,

      "settings": {

      } /*ChatProvider.Utils.settings*/
    }
  } //var ChatProvider

  ChatProvider.Utils.functions.addFriend({
    "Names": "bellash"
  });

}); //$(document).ready
```

P.S: for visibility sake, I added some space between line separating objects' properties.

Comment: Quick question, from a user's (not developer's) point of view: How do we access `Friends`, `People` and `Conferences`? Do we get them through a function or do we access the arrays directly?

Comment: Is this the real code you want reviewed, or some kind of example? I ask because `addFriend` pushes something onto the `Friends` array and then immediately pops it back off, which makes no sense, and the `alert` function seems contrived; it just wraps `window.alert`. In other words, it wouldn't do much good to review this code, as the code doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Dagg It is only an example. But I wonder if this is the best approach of coding in javascript instead of creating(bubling) separated functions in a .js file, my approach is good because it avoids conflicts between js file: am I wrong ?
@JosephtheDreamer for example, to access the Friends array, you just need to write ChatProvider.Friends[index] ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a once over:

- drop `functions`, it is too long and it's obvious that `alert` in `ChatProvider.utils.alert()` is a function. Furthermore, specifically for `alert`, that should be under `UI` in my mind
- Your functions are all over the place, I would think that adding a friend would be `ChatProvider.friends.add()` but you put it in `ChatProvider.Utils.functions.addFriend()`
- You treat your object as 1 singleton, what if you need more than 1 instance ?
- Maybe you are from a Java background, but namespacing the way you approach it should be avoided